# Use memcached in Google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, memcached

Is there a way to use memcached inside a google sheets script? I searched this libraries page:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#use_a_library

With no luck!
Thanks

P.S. you might ask, what on earth are you using memcached in googlesheets for :) it is a bit of a rabbit hole, using GPT3 inside google sheets (credits to Dr Alan Thompson) - and want to reduce the cost.

Comment: There is  a Cache Service

Answer (score 1):

There is a Cache Service in Apps Script but limited to small key / value (100ko)

In order to boost that, you might want to use a library that mix severals keys together.
This one is old but still working (and it's safe until 10mo) https://github.com/yinonavraham/GoogleAppsScripts/tree/master/EnhancedCacheService